# C++ Class won't execute function

Tags: c++, function, class, member

I want to write a simple backup program. Its not finished yet, but i've encountered a problem: My class responsible for setting the right path wont execute the worker which will copy the file. I don't know why and yes - i already looked up on any helping site i know. Here is my filecopy h code:

```
#ifndef __FILECOPY_H_INCLUDED__
#define __FILECOPY_H_INCLUDED__

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>

class filecopy
{
     std::string dest_path;
     std::string src_path;
public:
     filecopy(std::string, std::string);
 void filecopy_worker()
 {
      std::cout << "FILECOPY PROCESS STARTED" << std::endl;
      std::ifstream source(src_path);
      std::ofstream dest(dest_path);
      dest << source.rdbuf();
      source.close();
      dest.close();
 }
};

filecopy::filecopy(std::string a, std::string b)
{
     dest_path = a;
     src_path = b;
}

#endif
```

And here my main.cpp code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"filecopy.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if(argc != 3)
     {
          std::cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <filesource>" << std::endl;
          return 1;
     }
     else
     {
          filecopy target1(argv[2], argv[1]);
          std::cout << "TARGET ASSIGNED" << std::endl;
          std::cout << "EXECUTE FILEWORKER" << std::endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to? I do not see you calling any code which would copy anything.

Comment: I tried to call it like a member function, but that did not work. I removed that before copy&pasting. I don't understand why you are angry - this site isn't an exclusive club. I'm allowed to ask basic questions. And seriously - at some point you were a beginner to and missed something like this. Be polite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't execute the function because you never called it. Just add that function call

```
filecopy target1(argv[2], argv[1]);
target1.filecopy_worker();
```

Comment: The question has a specific problem, and I gave a small specific answer. What's the issue with that?

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day. And yes. It was a dumb question but i'm a beginner and you gave a great answer.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Encouraging further trivial nonsense, would be my guess. We require prior research here on SO. Mind you, though I agree you shouldn't have answered, I don't think we ought to be using downvotes to punish that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, this is why. The question has exactly 0 chances of being useful to future readers, so why do we encourage that? As for downvote, I wouldn't downvote if the answer hasn't been upvoted - thus encouraging more answers like that.

Comment: @SergeyA: Voting based on existing score is also wrong ;p